# Looking for a correct way to inject a jersey resource to a POJO class

Tags: dependency-injection, jersey, jersey-2.0, hk2

I have implemented Jersey SSE, My requirement is to send notificaion to connected clients when there is a data chnage on the server.

Well My SSE is working, now I am trying to tie it up with the code in POJO class which detects data chnage.

My resource looks like this

```
package org.example;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.sse.OutboundSseEvent;
import javax.ws.rs.sse.Sse;
import javax.ws.rs.sse.SseEventSink;
import org.jvnet.hk2.annotations.Service;

@Service
@Path("events")
public class SSEResource {

    @Context
    Sse sse;

    private SSEConnectionManager connectionManager;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        connectionManager = SSEConnectionManager.getInstance();
        connectionManager.initialize(sse);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public void getServerSentEvents(@Context SseEventSink eventSink, @Context UriInfo uri) {

        MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = uri.getQueryParameters();

        String closeParam = queryParams.getFirst("close");
        String clientIdParam = queryParams.getFirst("clientId");

        System.out.println("Client ID Parameter: " + clientIdParam);

        // Check if clientIdParam is missing or empty
        if (clientIdParam == null || clientIdParam.isEmpty()) {
            // Send a message to enter the clientId
            sendEventToClient(eventSink, "Please enter a valid clientId!");
            // Close the SSE connection since clientId is not provided
            eventSink.close();
            return; // Return early
        }

        if (closeParam != null && clientIdParam != null && !clientIdParam.isEmpty()) {
            // Close the SSE connection immediately
            eventSink.close();
            return; // Return early without sending the welcome message
        }

        // Check if the client has an existing connection
        if (connectionManager.isConnected(clientIdParam)) {
            connectionManager.closeConnection(clientIdParam);
        }

        // Add the connection to the SSEConnectionManager
        connectionManager.addConnection(clientIdParam, eventSink);

        // Send a welcome message to the client
        sendEventToClient(eventSink, "Welcome to SSE, Client " + clientIdParam + "!");
    }

    // Method to send an SSE event to a specific client
    private void sendEventToClient(SseEventSink eventSink, String data) {
        final OutboundSseEvent event = sse.newEventBuilder().name("message-to-client").data(String.class, data).build();
        eventSink.send(event);
    }


    public void sendEventToSpecificClient(String clientId, String message) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Client ID Parameter: " + clientId);
            if (clientId != null && !clientId.isEmpty()) {
                // Check if the client is connected
                if (connectionManager.isConnected(clientId)) {
                    try {
                        sendEventToClient(connectionManager.getConnection(clientId), message);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // Handle any exceptions that occur during sending the event
                        System.out.println("Error sending event to Client " + clientId + ": " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Client " + clientId + " not connected!");
                }
            }
        } finally {
            // eventSink.close(); // Close the SseEventSink in the finally block
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("close/{clientId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String closeConnection(@PathParam("clientId") String clientId) {
        if (clientId != null && !clientId.isEmpty()) {
            if (connectionManager.isConnected(clientId)) {
                connectionManager.closeConnection(clientId);
                return "SSE connection closed for client " + clientId;
            } else {
                return "Client " + clientId + " not connected!";
            }
        } else {
            return "Invalid client ID!";
        }
    }


    public void broadcastEvent(String message) {
        final OutboundSseEvent event = sse.newEventBuilder().name("broadcast").mediaType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE).data(String.class, message).build();

        // Broadcast the event to all connected clients
        connectionManager.getBroadcaster().broadcast(event);
    }
}
```

What I want to be able to is to call sendEventToSpecificClient() or broadcastEvent() from my POJO class

For testing sake I created this, but sseResource is always null

```
import javax.inject.Inject;


public class MainApp {

    @Inject
    SSEResource sseResource;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Simulate the client ID and message
        String clientId = "123";
        String message = "This is a test message.";

        new MainApp().call(clientId, message);


    }

    void call(String clientId, String message) {

        // Call the sendEventToSpecificClient method to send the event
        sseResource.sendEventToSpecificClient(clientId, message);
    }
}
```

Here's is MyApplication.java

```
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        // Register your resource classes or packages here using packages(), register(), etc.
        packages("org.example");

        // Register the AppLifecycleListener
        register(AppLifecycleListener.class);

        // Register the AbstractBinder with the bindings for dependency injection
        register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                // Bind the SSEResource class to itself (no need to specify the same class again)
                bind(SSEResource.class).to(SSEResource.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How Can properly inject the SSEresource in normal POJO class? I am using HK2 which comes with jersey.

Comment: Of course `MainApp.sseResource` is null, it would have to be the HK2 who instantiates the MainApp class not to be null. But is you who instantiates it in the `main()` method.

Comment: There are ways to inject things into classes you new up yourself (there is an inject API on ServiceLocator).  However this practice is generally frowned upon (except when doing unit tests)